# Forward Planning Heuristic- How to calculate hmax and hadd?

Tags: heuristics, planning

I am trying to understand the concept of the forward planning heuristics hmax and hadd. I've found some resources online, but I really can't understand how to calculate the value of hmax and hadd?

Here the resources I am referring to:

http://ai.cs.unibas.ch/_files/teaching/fs16/ai/slides/ai36-handout4.pdf

I understand that in hmax we consider the maximization of the costs and for hadd we do summation of the costs.

[heuristic value of hmax and hadd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5HSm.png)

How are these (circled in the image) values are calculated? Since the initial state is {a}, hence I am assuming that the heuristic value of initial state is assumed to be 0. Am I right?

In general, what is the heuristic value of an initial state?

Thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

hadd and hmax calculates the cost for achieving the facts from the goal definition. so it recursively calculates the h-values for all facts in the goal condition and the sum/max of the preconditions of the achieving actions (actions making the facts true)

The heuristic value of a initial state(or any state) is an indication of how "far" the state fulfilling the goal condition is from the current state.

Hope this puts you on the right track